# how to set baseuri in converterproperties in itext7 html to pdf converter

Tags: c#, html, pdf

[after converting into pdf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Npe9Q.png) I am trying to convert html to pdf using Itext7. I want bootstrap css to be included in pdf. I am trying to set baseuri but it is not working.
**here is my code :**

```
using (MemoryStream stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
    {
        ConverterProperties properties = new ConverterProperties();
        properties.SetBaseUri("/css/"); // I tried this in many ways 
        properties.SetFontProvider(new DefaultFontProvider(true, true, true));
        HtmlConverter.ConvertToPdf(GridHtml, new PdfWriter(stream), properties);
        return File(stream.ToArray(), "application/pdf", "test1.pdf");
    }
```

[this is the view before downloading in browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kLf5L.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

include your css file in html content like this `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mycss.css"/>`

and set base uri of your css content

```
ConverterProperties properties = new ConverterProperties();
properties.SetBaseUri("Content//css//");
```