# How to convert HTML C# code to pdf, using api2pdf/htmlagilitypack

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to convert HTML code written in C# to a PDF but getting issues when trying to do so. I get an error that says cannot HTMLAgilityPack.HTMLDocument object to Api2PdfChromeHtmltoPDFRequest. Is there a way to do so with these 2 libraries, or any better solutions?

```
var html = String.Format(@"<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><h1> Hello world </h1> </html>");

var doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(html)

Api2Pdf.Api2PdfResult emailConversionResult = a2pClient.Chrome.HtmlToPdf(doc);
```

Comment: The following may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69210758/itext7-htmlconverter-does-not-display-gif/69212530#69212530

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the documentation, HtmlToPdf is expecting an  `ChromeHtmlToPdfRequest` object (https://github.com/Api2Pdf/api2pdf.dotnet/blob/ba7da6496a45e1e07627158bc76d9ea48cdc6255/Api2Pdf.DotNet/RequestModels.cs#L42)

This is also what the error is trying to tell you. You are passing in an object of type `HTMLAgilityPack.HTMLDocument`, yet the HtmlToPdf method is expecting an object of type `ChromeHtmlToPdfRequest`. The compiler then complains that it cannot convert the first to the latter and throws an error at you.

So your code should look like this:

```cs
var emailConversionResult = a2pClient.Chrome.HtmlToPdf(new ChromeHtmlToPdfRequest
{
     Html = html
});
```

`Html` here is a string. So if you must use HtmlAgilityPack for some reason, you can also use this snippet:

```cs
var emailConversionResult = a2pClient.Chrome.HtmlToPdf(new ChromeHtmlToPdfRequest
{
     Html = doc.DocumentNode.OuterHtml
});
```