# itext7 html to pdf - vb example please?

Tags: vb.net, itext7, html-to-pdf, pdfhtml

Please can someone provide me with a simple example of converting a file from HTML to PDF in VB? I can find Java and C# examples but nothing using VB.

Comment: Unless the C# is doing something interesting, it should translate directly to VB.  I'd suggest that you try translating a C# example and update your question with any details that cause problems.

Answer (score 0):

The following shows how to use NuGet packages `iText7` and `itext7.pdfhtml` to convert HTML to a PDF file.

**VS 2022**:

- Open Visual Studio 2022
- Click [image]
- Click **File**
- Select **New**
- Select **Project**
- For filter, select: [image]
- [image]
- Click **Next**
- Enter desired project name (ex: ConvertHtmlToPdfTest)
- Select desired .NET Framework (ex: .NET Framework 4.8)
- Click **Create**

**Open Toolbox**:

- In VS menu, click **View**
- Select **Toolbox**

**Open Solution Explorer**:

- In VS menu, click **View**
- Select **Solution Explorer**

**Open Properties Window**

- In VS menu, click **View**
- Select **Properties Window**

**Set Default package management format** (optional)

- In VS menu, click **Tools**
- Select **Options...**
- Expand **NuGet Package Manager**
- Select **General**
- Under "Package Management", set **Default package management format** to **PackageReference**
- Click **OK**

**Download/install NuGet package** (iText7):

- In Solution Explorer, right-click <project name> (ex: ConvertHtmlToPdfTest)
- Select **Manage NuGet Packages...**
- Click **Browse** tab
- In the search box type: **iText7**
- Select **iText7**
- Select desired version (ex: 7.2.3)
- Click **Install**
- If a MessageBox appears, click **OK**

**Download/install NuGet package** (iText7.pdfhtml):

- In Solution Explorer, right-click <project name> (ex: ConvertHtmlToPdfTest)
- Select **Manage NuGet Packages...**
- Click **Browse** tab
- In the search box type: **iText7.pdfhtml**
- Select **iText7.pdfhtml**
- Select desired version (ex: 4.0.3)
- Click **Install**
- If a MessageBox appears, click **OK**

**Add a module**: (name: HelperiText7.vb)

- In VS menu, click **Project**
- Select **Add New Item...**
- Select **Module** (name: HelperiText7.vb)
- Click **Add**

**HelperiText7.vb**:

```
Imports System.IO
Imports iText.Html2pdf

Module HelperiText7
    Public Sub CreatePdf(htmlFilename As String, pdfFilename As String, Optional baseUri As String = Nothing)
        Dim pdfData As Byte() = Nothing

        If Not File.Exists(htmlFilename) Then
            Throw New Exception($"Error: '{htmlFilename}' doesn't exist.")
        End If

        Using fs As FileStream = New FileStream(htmlFilename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
            Using ms As MemoryStream = New MemoryStream()
                'when specifying HTML as a string And the HTML includes
                'a resource that uses relative paths,
                'it's necessary to specify the baseUri (path)

                'create new instance
                Dim properties As ConverterProperties = New ConverterProperties()

                If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(baseUri) Then
                    'set value
                    properties.SetBaseUri(baseUri)
                Else
                    'get folder name that HTML file exists in
                    Dim folderName As String = Path.GetDirectoryName(htmlFilename)

                    'set value
                    properties.SetBaseUri(folderName)
                End If

                'Debug.WriteLine($"BaseURI: {properties.GetBaseUri()}")

                'convert HTML to PDF
                HtmlConverter.ConvertToPdf(fs, ms, properties)

                'save to Byte()
                pdfData = ms.ToArray()
            End Using

            'save to PDF file
            File.WriteAllBytes(pdfFilename, pdfData)
        End Using
    End Sub

    Public Sub CreatePdfFromHtmlString(htmlString As String, pdfFilename As String, baseUri As String)
        Dim pdfData As Byte() = Nothing

        Using ms As MemoryStream = New MemoryStream()
            'when specifying HTML as a string And the HTML includes
            'a resource that uses relative paths,
            'it's necessary to specify the baseUri (path)

            'create new instance
            Dim properties As ConverterProperties = New ConverterProperties()

            'set value
            properties.SetBaseUri(baseUri)

            'convert HTML to PDF
            HtmlConverter.ConvertToPdf(htmlString, ms, properties)

            'save to Byte()
            pdfData = ms.ToArray()
        End Using

        'save to PDF file
        File.WriteAllBytes(pdfFilename, pdfData)
    End Sub
End Module
```

---

For testing, I used the following:

**test.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>HTML Test</h2>

    <div>
        <IMG src="./images/strawberry.jpg" ALT="strawberry">
    </div>

    <p>
        <div>
            This is a test message
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Note**: In the HTML above, the image uses a relative path.

**File/Folder structure**:

[image: FileAndFolderStructure]

**images\strawberry.jpg**: [image: strawberry.jpg]

---

The following demonstrates converting `test.html` to a PDF file.

```
Using ofd As OpenFileDialog = New OpenFileDialog()
    ofd.Filter = "HTML File (*.html)|*.html"
    ofd.Title = "Select HTML Filename"

    If ofd.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
        Using sfd As SaveFileDialog = New SaveFileDialog()
            sfd.Filter = "PDF File (*.pdf)|*.pdf"
            sfd.Title = "Select PDF Filename To Save As"
            If sfd.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
                'the image in the HTML uses a relative path
                'set baseUri = to the folder that contains the HTML file
                Dim baseUri As String = Path.GetDirectoryName(ofd.FileName)
                Debug.WriteLine($"baseUri: {baseUri}")

                'convert HTML to PDF
                HelperiText7.CreatePdf(ofd.FileName, sfd.FileName, baseUri)
            End If
        End Using
    End If
End Using
```

**Resources**:

- [pdfHTML: configuration options](https://itextpdf.com/blog/technical-notes/pdfhtml-configuration-options)
- [Hello HTML to PDF](https://kb.itextpdf.com/home/it7kb/ebooks/itext-7-converting-html-to-pdf-with-pdfhtml/chapter-1-hello-html-to-pdf)
- [how to set baseuri in converterproperties in itext7 html to pdf converter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62656047/how-to-set-baseuri-in-converterproperties-in-itext7-html-to-pdf-converter)
- [Itext7 HtmlConverter does not display gif](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69212530/10024425)

**Additional Resources**:

- [How to display Base64 images in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8499633/how-to-display-base64-images-in-html)
- [c# Image resizing to different size while preserving aspect ratio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1940581/c-sharp-image-resizing-to-different-size-while-preserving-aspect-ratio)